# How to translate "sink" in "carbon sink" or when dealing with electric fields

Tags: single-word-requests

In various scientific fields, there is a notion of *sources* and *sinks* for describing some kinds of flows or circulations. For instance, carbon dioxide is emitted by carbon sources (combustion, cement production) and sequestrated in carbon sinks (forest, oceans). Similarily, an electric field is represented with lines oriented from sources (positive charges) to sinks (negative charges).

*Source* translates easily as *fonto*. But what about *sink*?

In German, carbon sink is *Kohlenstoffsenke* (*Senke* means a geological depression). In French, it is *puits de carbone* (*puits* = well). In each case a water/hydrological metaphor is used.

My proposition is *elfluejo* (and accordingly *karbonelfluejo*), which retains the metaphor.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think  *malfonto* is quite natural here. You can use it for flows of liquids, for global circulation of carbon, for electric and other fields in physics or for vector fields in pure mathematics.

*Elfluejo* could be both *source* and *sink* depending on your point of view. Maybe *forfluejo* would be more unambiguous.

Comment: What about *alfluejo*? Would it work?

Comment: To me _alfluejo_ would be at least equally ambiguous, even implying _source_ rather than _sink_.

Comment: Indeed, *malfonto* is easily understandable and makes the symmetry clear.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough knowledge in this field to evaluate what would be relevant. In computer science, specialy in the compiler domain, one may use *fonto/celo* to transalte "source/target", for example in this [Internaciigo de komputilaj programoj](https://beta.wikiversity.org/wiki/Internaciigo_de_komputilaj_programoj/Internaciigo_kaj_lokecigo) course.

I tend to prefer to avoid analogical vocabulary when I'm inspired with a terminology which offer broader genericity. For example one may use "origin" rather than "source", to avoid the "[conceit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceit) trap". You may then use "termination" or whatever antonym you may like with possibility to add "pre-" "post-" and other [lexemes of generic progression](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Recherche:Lex%C3%A8mes_fran%C3%A7ais_relatifs_aux_structures#Progression_g.C3.A9n.C3.A9rique). I guess in esperanto it's even far easier with all the standard affixes.

Now, more specicaly, here are my trials:

- carbon sources: karbonaj fontoj/generantoj/emisiantoj/elasanto
- carbon sinks: karbonaj sorbantoj/retenantoj

Thus said, the proposed *elfluejo, forfluejo, *and* malfonto* all seems good to me.